# Insert value into a table and insert one extra column by PL./SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am inserting values from a cursor to two tables. Table A and B
but B will have one for extra column in it with

**QUERY**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fast_proc (p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100)
IS

TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF all_objects%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

    CURSOR c IS
    SELECT col1 ,col2,col3
    FROM dual;

BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO tableB LIMIT p_array_size ;

    FORALL i IN 1..tableB .COUNT
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES tableB (i);

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END fast_proc;
```

But this is giving me error as Status column is not getting filled. How can I insert all the values from the cursor and then add status as harcoded 'A'.

I cannot add it in the query as the same cursor will be used to insert in Table A.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor for this? And the statement `SELECT col1 , col2,col3 FROM dual;` is invalid to begin with (dual does not have a `col1`);

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a partial fetch in the cursor and insert it to the table and later going to add status to the table, why not do it at the same time?

```
CURSOR c IS
SELECT col1 ,col2,col3,'A'
FROM dual;
```

'A' is where the status column is coming.

And if you want to insert values only after the cursor fetch, then change your insert statement to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t2(col1 ,col2,col3) VALUES tableB(i);
```

Specify the columns where insertion should take place, ie, leave the status column out of it.